# Chuck has no bounds

Tags: java

At first it was to make a joke, but I really did not understand why my program does not crash :

```
public class ChuckNorris {
    char[] array;

    public boolean HaveBounds(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("Because Chuck Norris knows no bounds.");
        return false;
    }
    public ChuckNorris()
    {
        array = null;
    }

    public char getArrayId(int i)
    {
        return array[i];
    }



}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 12;
        ChuckNorris chuckNorris = new ChuckNorris();
        if(chuckNorris.HaveBounds(i))
        {
            char test = chuckNorris.getArrayId(i);
            System.out.println(test);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is the most humorous code I have seen in a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you return `false`

```
public boolean HaveBounds(int i)
{
    System.out.println("Because Chuck Norris knows no bounds.");
    return false;
}
```

and therefore you never reach

```
char test = chuckNorris.getArrayId(i);
```

which tries to access the array.

If it returned `true`, you would get a `NullPointerException` in the call to

```
public char getArrayId(int i)
{
    return array[i];
}
```

because `array` is `null`.

Comment: Good see ! I was not quite awake ! Chuck has bounds !